# Corona Vertices of a Hexagon

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Ok, so I'm trying to create hexagons for my game. The first option I had is to have several images of hexagon, but I'm having problems with clickable area since these images are positioned side-by-side.

So i guess my only option is to create objects using polygons. Here is a code from corona sdk's website:

```
local halfW = display.contentWidth * 0.5
local halfH = display.contentHeight * 0.5

local vertices = { 0,-110, 27,-35, 105,-35, 43,16, 65,90, 0,45, -65,90, -43,15, -105,-35, -27,-35, }

local o = display.newPolygon( halfW, halfH, vertices )
o.fill = { type="image", filename="mountains.png" }
o.strokeWidth = 10
o:setStrokeColor( 1, 0, 0 )
```

That code is for creating a star. But I don't know how to create a hexagon using vertices.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to create the vertices array:

```
local R = 45
local N = 6
local vertices = {}
local i = 0
for t = 0, 2*math.pi, 2*math.pi/N do
    i=i+1; vertices[i]= R*math.cos(t)
    i=i+1; vertices[i]= R*math.sin(t)
end
```

And this to draw the hexagon:

```
local halfW = display.contentWidth * 0.5
local halfH = display.contentHeight * 0.5

local hexagon = display.newPolygon( halfW, halfH, vertices )
hexagon.fill = { type="image", filename="mountains.png" }
hexagon.strokeWidth = 10
hexagon:setStrokeColor( 1, 0, 0 )
```

I chose `R=45` to produce a polygon of the same size of your star.

Comment: Just noting: to use this with the physics library, the for loop will need to go clockwise. `for t=0, -2*math.pi,-2*math.pi/N do`

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a graphics.newMask() to apply a mask to each image hex that would make the outside area not touchable.